# Displaying data Mysql in datalist

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

why `kategori_nama` didn't show in fatalist.

here my controller

```
function index(){
     $data['title']='Portal Database Buku';
     $data['dropdown']=$this->m->ambildataKategori('ref_kategori');
     $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

my models

```
function ambildataKategori(){
        return $this->db->get('ref_kategori');
    }
```

views

```
<input name="kategori_id">
                              <datalist>
                                <?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($dropdown)){ ?>
                                 <option value="<?php echo $rows["kategori_nama"];?>">
                                 <?php } ?>
                              </datalist>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is a little vague. Could you clarify the exact nature of the issue. Do you see any errors in your browsers console? Any PHP Errors being returned?

Comment: Also, I see you are attempting to `fetch_assoc()` from a MySQL Query. This assumes you have a proper Query with results. I do not see where `$dropdown` is defined.

Comment: You've explained that `kategori_nama` doesn't show up in your list, but could you give a bit more context around where this data is coming from? What have you tried so far?

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

**Note** : *make sure you have loaded database and model in controller or in autoload.php*

Your model method `ambildataKategori` should be like this

```
public function ambildataKategori()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('ref_kategori');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
       /*make sure your table has data
           print_r($query->result_array());
       */
       return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

Your view should be like this  :

```
<?php 
if ( ! empty($dropdown)){ ?>
    <datalist>
        <?php foreach($dropdown as $item) {?>
           <option value="<?php echo $item["kategori_nama"];?>">
        <?php }?>   
    </datalist>   
<?php }?>
```

for reference : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/index.html

Answer (score 1):

In Codeigniter 4 the helper `form_datalist(string $name, string $value, array $options)` is available within the form_helper in the same way as `form_dropdown()`.

Its worth flagging though, that the helper helpfully outputs an input type text as well - which you have no control over so may well want to edit that out of the helper!